# Why does tRPC's context get reset on every procedure (websockets)?

Tags: trpc.io

I'm trying to store state in the tRPC context between different procedures called by the same user. I use websockets/wsLink, so context is created once when the user first connects. This context mutation should only happen when a user calls a specific procedure.

However, It looks like the context properties are reset whenever a procedure is called by the user.

However, mutating properties **of** properties works to share state between procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the code and found that it's a limitation caused by [spreading](https://github.com/trpc/trpc/blob/f093a598d283b0320e0c1a3ace6b9a1233ac88d9/packages/server/src/core/internals/procedureBuilder.ts#L373):

```js
              ctx:
                nextOpts && 'ctx' in nextOpts
                  ? { ...callOpts.ctx, ...nextOpts.ctx }
                  : callOpts.ctx,
```

It's an implementation detail of tRPC, where 2 contexts are **merged** together to support middlewares adding properties to the context.

My recommendation would be **avoid** changing properties on context directly, because you would be editing a temporarily generated context for the last middleware called. If you edit anything inside specific properties, these will exist because these were just copied from the original context.